# Path Following for a Differential Drive Robot - MATLAB & Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I  have the Kinematical model of Skid-Steering Robot with Differential Drive is illustrated in the below figure. Lambda_L is the Left wheel slipping so Lambda_R  they are assumed constants 0.01, c is half of the distance between the tow wheels, r is the radios of the wheel. I'm trying to  simulink (sine wave) trajectory for the robot, I mean determine the speeds command for the Right wheel and the left wheel to let the Robot follow sinusoidal trajectory.

I started from the coordinate of the robot assuming sinusoidal trajectory to be seen in (x,y) graph of simulink, I put 
           y=sin(t) && x=t;
so:

```
           Vox=1, Voy= cos(t);
           Vmx=sqrt(Vox^2+Voy^2)
           theta=arctan(Voy/Vox)
```

so:

```
          wz=cos(t)/(1+sin(t)^2)
```

then I get the speeds must be applied is Like:

```
         WL=0.5(Vmx/a -wz/b)
         WR=WL+wz/b : a=(1-Lamda_L)*r/2;
                      b=(1-Lamda_L)*r/(2*c);
```

**in the simulation I get the following error:**
"Derivative input 1 of 'sinwave/Integrator1' at time 0 is Inf or NaN. Stopping simulation. There may be a singularity in the solution. If not, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)."

the parameters are:

```
  r=0.25;
  c=0.5;
  lamda_L=0.01;
  lamda_R=0.01;
```

anyone have an idea where is the problem

[the files  contain matlab code and simulink.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9uneop93bz4lk1/Model.rar?dl=0)

[the simulation is provided with the Image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2bYN.jpg)

Comment: I think the problem is in the integrator input , check the input your integrator is most probably overflowing

Comment: attach a scope at the integrator input , you probably have a very sudden and very high change in the value and most probably you are dividing something with a really small value before the in put which is causing that

Comment: when i put a scope before the integrator  i  couldn't  see the signal, I removed the integrator and watch the signal this is  on dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ja4mubreyp8703u/inte.jpg?dl=0

Comment: which element block I can use to avoid zero crossing

Comment: Observe first second of your scopedata , Its all Nan or infinity which is causing your integrator to overflow and that is the reason your integrator cannot compute, excluse that data and your model will work fine

Comment: use a saturation block in the Simulink which will limit the max value

Comment: I tried and set the upper limit to 1 and the  Lower limit to -1, but the same problem  I get :(

Comment: did you add it right before the integrator ? set the limits to -10 and 10